# Control execution in a Parallel.For

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

In this parallel execution:

```
         Parallel.For(0, 100, i =>
         {
             Console.WriteLine(i);
         });
```

I am trying to get the same values of the below usual loop, so the "i" is always gave in an ascendent order, 0, 1, 2, 3, ... , 100

```
        for(int i=0; i <=100; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
```

Is this possible, how could I control this parallel for execution regarding the order of the index ?

Comment: Short Answer: No. Long Answer: Because the lambda you're declaring will run on multiple threads, the ordering can no longer be guaranteed, unless you synchronize them, in which case you're defeating the purpose.

Comment: And how could I synchronize them ? Please give me an example !

Comment: Attempting to do so defeats the purpose of parallelizing the whole thing in the first place. I will add an answer that addresses this possibility...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once threading is involved, the order of execution is no longer guaranteed. You can technically get the results you're asking for by synchronizing everything, like so:

```
int actualIndex = 0;
var lockObject = new object();
Parallel.For(0, 100, i =>
{
    lock(lockObject) Console.WriteLine(actualIndex++); 
});
```

But, doing so simply adds the overhead of parallelism, then ensures that only one thread is doing something at a time - in other words, it's much *worse* than simply doing a regular `for` loop!

If you need things to happen serially, the best you can do is either serialize via synchronization like `lock`, or... simply do it serially.

What are you trying to accomplish, exactly?

Comment: Inside of my serial for loops I have some huge calculations which are taken a lot of time... Changing those serial for loops to parallel ones, was given much better time results but because the order of indexes was broken some strange results occured.

Comment: @user5631730: Try creating a wrapper class (or use a tuple), do your math, but store the index before doing the math, then reorder the data when you're done.

Answer (score 1):

If you want that the execution of `i` starts after `i - 1` is done then there is no parallelism left and using a parallel loop is pointless.

A clever answer would be to build a string that has the 101 numbers separated by newlines and then print it. But that does not help you with your real use case I assume.

Comment: A clever answer indeed. But you dont need a magic string, just an array of the right length, using "i" as the index

Comment: @SilverSolver yeah, my goal was to maximize the share of the work that is parallel. So if you build an array you still need to iterate it and print it one by one. Anyway, this is a contrived scenario. The key message is: The OP must change his approach or give up.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only results in ascending order, then this may work for you:

```
var results = new Dictionary<int>();
object lock = new object();
Parallel.For(0, 100, i =>
         {
             // here code runs in parallel
             lock(lock) { 
                // here code runs sequentially
                results[i]; 
             }
         });

// results from 0..100
var r = results.OrderBy(x => x.Key).Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

`lock` creates what is known as critical section - inside `lock` block of code may be only one thread at time, other threads must wait.

Parallel programming is a huge and complicated topic, here is a best course for C# programmers I ever read http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx